# IllegalStateException while creating BlobServiceClient for azure-storage-blob

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to use `azure-storage-blob` client SDK to get blobs from Azure in my `Spring 5` web app. I am getting `IllegalStateException` while creating a `BlobServiceClient` to download the blobs. Below is the code I am using for creating the client.

```
var accountName = "account";
var accountKey = "accountKey";
var credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
var endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName);
BlobServiceClient storageClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();
```

I get an exception with the message: Cannot find any HttpClient provider on the classpath - unable to create a default HttpClient instance. By debugging the code I figured out that the exception is thrown while creating a default HTTPClient and I tried to manually provide the HTTP client like below

```
HttpClient httpClient = new NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder().build();
BlobServiceClient storageClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).httpClient(httpClient).buildClient();
```

With this i get the error mesage `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient`

I have added the dependency `com.azure:azure-storage-blob;V12.3.0` and also manually added `com.azure:azure-core-http-netty;V1.2.0`. I have no compile errors and I have also verified that all the dependencies mentioned in the `com.azure:azure-storage-blob` are present in the lib directory of my WAR. Could someone please provide some pointer on what I am doing wrong here

Comment: I posted an answer how I use the BlobServiceClient. Maybe it helps. Otherwise, can you post you pom.xml?

Comment: I have tried the solution posted below earlier but had no success. Link for my pom file https://pastebin.com/7BUh3jhx

Answer (score 0):

For me it works using a the connection-string:

```
    @Bean
    public BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient(
            @Value("${azure.storage.connection.string}") String connectionString,
            @Value("${azure.storage.containername}") String containerName) {
        final var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
        return blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    }
```